# open(filename, 'w+') causes Permission Error 13

Tags: python

I created a program written in Python, it worked fine on my computer but when I sent it to the client this error popped up.

`PermissionError: [Error 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/........../part-00100.csv`
-> I replaced full path with dots (...)

due to this line:
`csv_file = open(csv_filename, 'w+', encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='')`

Code:

```
jsonFile = filedialog.askopenfilename(master = root, title = "Select a JSON file")
lists = jsonFile.split('/')
paths = lists[:-1]
fileName = lists[-1].split('.json')[0] + '.csv'
csv_filename = '/'.join(paths)
csv_filename = '/'.join([csv_filename, fileName])
```

**final csv_filename** = C:/Users/........../part-00100.csv (I replaced full path with dots).

He tried running it as administrator and still gives him same problem.

I want to create that file without error, any suggestions?
Please notice that it works on my machine perfectly. I don't know why it doesn't work for him!

Comment: The reason it doesn't work for him is... because he doesn't have permission to write that file, as the error says. We can't say any more than that from the information you've given.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I understand. This file doesn't exist and I added 'w+' to create new file. I need a solution to create the file and be able to write to it.

Comment: Perhaps the directory does not exist.

Comment: Nope, it exists. I ask him first to choose a file (with Tkinter filedialog) then I take same directory and create the file there.

Comment: have you try using pandas for this. will be very easy to do it in pandas, also what operation system your client has. ???

Comment: Thank you so much for your message. He uses Windows. I tried with Pandas and it really worked but because I am processing very large files (and in Pandas I had to store whole dataframe to variable) pandas took too much memory on RAM, so now I open a CSV file and write row by row without storing anything to memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look the way you handle paths its very dangerous.
its better if you use "OS"

```
import os
from tkinter import filedialog

path_to_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title = "Select a JSON file")
dir_path= os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(path_to_file))
basename = os.path.abspath(os.path.basename(path_to_file))
fileName = basename.split('.json')[0] + '.csv'
csv_filename = os.path.join(basename, fileName)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this and for suggesting to use Pandas instead. I truly appreciate your effort.